# ROR: How to sort array with .limit method

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-order-by

I want to show the records based on created date DESC.But I have to select only one record for each user based on created date DESC. For that I am using the .limit method to get only one record from database and .order method to sort the array like this:

```
@messages = Message.where('FromUserId = ? or ToUserId = ?', user.id, user.id).order('created_at DESC').limit(1)
array = Array.new

@messages.each do |message| 
  response = Hash.new
  response[:id]=message.id
  response[:from]=message.FromUserId
  response[:to]=message.ToUserId
  response[:date]=message.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p")
  response[:content]=message.MessageContent
  array.push(response)
end
```

But it is showing the old record on the top when I loop the array I also tried using this one:

```
@messges = array.sort { |a,b| a[:date] <=> b[:date] }
```

But again I get the same result.Can someone tell me what is the right way to do it.

Comment: wouldn't `limit(1)` return a _single_ element?

Comment: Yes it will return single result,But after adding values to array can I sort them by date DESC ?

Comment: `response[:date]` contain `string` not `date`, use this `response[:date] = message.created_at` and try sort again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#sort_by` with `Array#reverse`. If you populate "array" in different places then make sure you have same object type

```
@messges.sort_by! {|m| m[:date].to_s } # sorted oldest to newest
@messges.sort_by! {|m| m[:date].to_s }.reverse # sorted newest to oldest
```

Comment: It works very fine, thanks very much @Pavel Evstigneev